# When importing a database any page with a wp_query in doesn't work

Tags: wp-query, page-template

I've noticed this a lot, when I export a database from a test site and import it into a live site, any (or most) page with a wp_query in it doesn't show up correctly (It shows the theme, but as though I'm viewing a page with no content in)

But if I create another page, using the same template as the one with the wp_query in it works just fine (As long as I don't give it the same slug). It also works correctly if I simply rename the page slug

Does anyone know why this might be? This is a sample wp_query that I use;

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'offers',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'asc'
    );
    $offer_query = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $offer_query->have_posts() ) : $offer_query->the_post();
?>

    <!-- SOME FANCY CONTENT HERE -->

<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: I notice issues sometimes when moving websites from local to live, but those issues are usually solved by visiting the Permalink configuration page. wp-admin/options-permalink.php
I go there and just click save. Once you click save that ensures that the htaccess file is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Moving a site from local to live should not effect queries like that one, where there are not hard-coded values like post IDs or post slugs that might have changed with the migration (depending on how you migrate).

What could conceivably be happening is that the page/page-template association gets broken. That information is stored in the `$wpdb->postmeta` table under the key `_wp_page_template`. Depending on how you migrated the associated post ID could be different than stored in the database. Your statement that "... if I create another page, using the same template as the one with the wp_query in it works just fine" seems to support the theory.